# Cordova + Nuxt 3 : Failed to load resource : net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: android, cordova, cors, nuxt.js

I'm working on an hybrid app with Nuxt 3, and Cordova to make an APK for android systems.
Unfortunatly, I encounter some CORS error when I try to launch the app.
This Nuxt app is verry simple and does not contain any api or external domain calls. It only load CSS, JS and pictures contained into the dist/ folder.

I have already tried to add this configuration to my config.xml file :

```xml
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <allow-intent href="*" />
    <preference name="hostname" value="localhost" />
```

I have also tried to add CSPs manually on my  tag like this :

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

I know this is of course a very insecure configuration, but nothing does the job. I always get the error "`Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`" for every files located on subfolders like localhost/_nuxt/myfile.css.
It seems that my config is being completly ignored.

I'm using chrome://inspect to debugging my app, and I use this configuration to compile my app :

```
Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 17.0.6
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: installed android-34,android-33
Gradle: installed C:\my\installation\folder\gradle-8.1.1\bin\gradle.BAT
```

And I use Cordova version 12.0.0

Please let me know if you need more informations.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appear a bit more tricky than appearances. In deed, Cordova do not ignore every folders, but only folders that start with "_" character. This is why my /_nuxt/ folder that contain the builded webapp resulted to this error when trying to accessing ressources.

To resolve this issue, and have a renamed build folder as default, you must add this config into the nuxt.config.ts file :

```
 app: {
     buildAssetsDir: "/BuildFolderWithoutUnderscore/",
 },
```